# Prometheus target not getting identified

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

It seems that my target is not getting scraped by prometheus (it does not show up in my targets list). My target is a Raspberry Pi with node exporter configured - I verified that I am able to see the metrics being exposed by my target.

Here is my prometheus config:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: prometheus
   static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
      labels:
         group: 'localhost'

    
    - targets: ['192.168.254.92:9100']
      labels:
         group: 'RSP'
```

what is wrong with my config or setup?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. The bind mount was pointing to the wrong configuration file on the prometheus Docker instance:

```
docker run --rm --detach --name prometheushomenet --publish 9090:9090 --volume prometheus-volume:/prometheus  --volume "$(pwd)"/Desktop/Prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.ym prom/prometheus
```